# Can my neighbour's bees attack my bees

Tags: insects, instinct

I want to get into apiculture, but my neighbour has bees. I read somewhere that his bees might attack my bees or my bees migrating to my neighbour's hives. How to avoid this?

Comment: I do not have the experience to answer the question as-is. But from the perceived hidden message, the answer you actually need is: first learn everything you can about bee-keeping. After you exhausted the possibilities, concentrate on the details.

Comment: Bees don't care who their "owner" is, they only care about their own hive. So if you learn how close a single owner can place several hives, you also know the minimum distance you should keep to your neighbors hive. I don't know anything about apiculture, but I've seen several bee hives very close together, so I don't expect many problems there.

Comment: This might not be suitable to this Stack Exchange. I mean, we don't have to close this, but I wouldn't expect a good answer to this.

Comment: This is no way an answer, but my uncle does some beekeeping and he said if another hive is directly on the way to the path to rich flower fields or water, hives do attack each other.